# Excel and Google Sheets: SUM-ing spreadsheet data range when column has #N/A

Tags: excel, sumifs

I am trying to SUM $-values with a filter that matches a specific text but there are #N/A errors preventing it.

How can I get it to ignore the #N/A errors while keeping the match?

I want to sum the $-values of "Quarter 1" in column B using column A's "Quarter 1" as the filter word, but because there is a #N/A in B13, it is preventing the total sum.

I tried `=sumif((A1:A17,"Quarter 1",B1:B17),"<>#N/A")` but it just returns #N/A.

I tried `=sumif((A1:A17,"Quarter 1",B1:B17),">0")` but it returns #ERROR.

I tried `=SUMIF(IMPORTRANGE(A1:A17,"Quarter 1",B1:B17), ">0")` but it returns $0.00.

[image]

The reason why I get #N/A to begin with is because I am pulling the data from another worksheet in the workbook using `=SUM(FILTER(G2:G,M2:M=V2,B2:B>=W8,B2:B<=X8))`. The workbook contains several worksheets; each worksheet is an individual person. This formula sums up the $-amount (G) a person has spent under the specific keyword "Travel" (V2) in the column of expense-type (M) during a specific quarter (W8 and X8).

G is the $

M is the filter range

V2 is the filter keyword

W8 and X8 are the date ranges (01/01/2019 and 03/31/2019)

Since for example, Quarter 2 (April-June) hasn't started yet, it returns a #N/A value for now. But I also know that not every individual person will have spent under this expense-type which may leave it as a #N/A.

And I am returning this value (or #N/A value) using `='PERSON 1'!Y8` from their worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel you would use SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"quarter 1",B:B,"<>#N/A")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this idea works

[Screenshot of formula showing IFERROR to ignore #N/A values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAmpm.jpg)